# Why is there this read_fwf() error?

Tags: pandas

When i am trying to read the fixed width file, it gives me that

```
Exception: Index (columns 0) have duplicated values ['12345']
```

The thing is, even though I have duplicated values, I still want the data incorporated. How could one get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `read_fwf()` with argument `index_col=None` to tell it that there are no index columns (which must be unique over all rows) -- it will automatically index rows with an integer starting at zero.

Comment: another problem I have now is that it reads it, but then it outputs weird values when i try calling the DF. It outputs things like x.1, 3, non-null values. I better post this as a new question.